# Is it possible to sync iCloud (iPhone) calendar with Outlook (PC) calendar?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, iphone, calendar

I've tried to install iCloud application for Windows but it does not have a checkbox to select "Calendars, Contacts, ..". I've also tried to install Outlook app on my iPhone but still when I create a calendar event on my iPhone it does not sync to my outlook account on PC.

Is there any way?

Comment: Who’s the email provider?  I have a MS exchange online account for email, but we actually use an iCloud shared calendar as the main calendar.  I’d have to research how the magic happens, but I see everything on my Outlook calendar on laptop.

Comment: The email provider is outlook.com

Answer (score 0):

In the settings on the iPhone, you should be able to add an account. In iOS 11, it will be in Settings->Accounts and Passwords. If you select “Add Account”, there is an option for outlook there. Enter your outlook credentials, and follow through the prompts. You can likely disable mail, notes, and contacts if you only want the calendar.

Open Settings->Calendar on the iPhone and find “Default Calendar”. Set this to be the Outlook account you just added to the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [Synchronize Outlook and Apple iPhone or iPod touch calendars](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/synchronize-outlook-and-apple-iphone-or-ipod-touch-calendars-be7a12eb-fe76-4346-ae13-b54249db7f9c)

1. Connect your iPhone or iPod touch to your computer using the cable provided with your device or by placing the iPhone or iPod touch in the Apple Universal Dock.
   iTunes opens automatically when connected to your computer.
2. In iTunes, in the source list, under Devices, click the entry for your iPhone or iPod touch.
3. Click the Info tab.
4. Under Calendars, click Sync calendars from, and then click Outlook.
5. Do one of the following:
   To synchronize all calendars, click All calendars.
   To limit the calendars that are synchronized, click Selected calendars, and then click the calendars you want to synchronize.

Note: To select multiple calendars, press Ctrl as you click each calendar name.

6. Click Apply.

Comment: That will only sync them when the phone is connected to the computer. Given the asker wants to sync from the phone to the computer, I would be doubtful they want to have to plug their phone in to sync it.